# Optimising MySQL: Why I see Command SLEEP in phpMyAdmin (current Processes)?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I started optimising MySQL and in **phpMyAdmin -> Status -> Processes** I see:

[image: Current Processes]

As I understand the last Process ID: **1228226** is for Query "To show current Processes" so the lower ID numbers was executed before this query.

Somehow the Process ID: **1228225** is not in the list.

How can I trace this **Sleep** command or Process ID? Will it delay queries? The Status looks empty, does this mean process is already completed or not started yet?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Sleeping processes are connections that are opened but not doing anything right now. They are waiting for new commands to execute or to be closed (explicitly or timeout).

Comment: @kaczmen Ahh.. I think I should have to call `wpdb->close();` in end of my scripts to fix this. Will try now. Thank you for helping.